# set label position with priority constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have one label to the right side of parent view.On top of label there is a view.I have given below constraints to label.

1. Align leading to top view (constant<16) LOW PRIORITY
2. Top space from parent view
3. Trailing space to parent view (constant=28) HIGH PRIORITY

I want when text inside the label increase it should change it's position.it should move towards left but at the same time it should also move towards right.I mean should increase it's width in both directions.As of now it's only moving towards left & keeping fix position from right.

Please tell how can i achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you set `center alignment` for `label alignment` you should get answer you want.Also give same `priority` to `leading` and `trailing`.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as the trailing space to super view constraint will most likely always win, as you have observed.

The **width** and **height** of the label is taken care of by its **intrinsic content size** and hence no constraints are needed for that. As far as position goes, the **y** is taken care of by the top space constraint. Finally the **x** will need a constraint that will allow it to grow in both directions as mentioned. To enable this behaviour remove the leading and trailing constraints and add a **horizontally centered constraint**. This will centre the label to its super views centre. To offset the position left or right you may choose a constant value or use the multiplier property.

The multiplier is good for positioning a certain percentage of the superview regardless of its size. e.g.: if the superview is the root view then a multiplier value of 0.5 places the label quarter of the way across the view, 1.0 makes the centre x align exactly, 1.5 makes it 3/4 across from the left.